# ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "audiotestsrc"

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to write a simple audio streaming application with C using Gstreamer library (gstreamer1.0-libav) on ubuntu 16.04. I was testing the gstreamer1.0-tools with a simple "gst-launch audiotestsrc ! alsasink" command, but each time I run this I get the following error: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "audiotestsrc". I've tried running the command on different path locations such as usr/bin/, usr/local/lib/, etc., but I cannot seem to figure out where Ubuntu installed the Gstreamer binaries that let me run these commands. Also, I'm assuming, with my lack of experience with linux, that the problem is that I'm not running this command on the right directory. I'm following this guide: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html#. Could someone shed some light on this matter? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, although I'm still unsure whether this is a fix. Doing more research I found this great resource http://labs.isee.biz/index.php/Example_GStreamer_Pipelines. I replaced "gst-launch audiotestsrc ! alsasink" with "gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! alsasink" and that did the trick. The problem was with the version on the gst-launch command. Hope this can help anyone. Any other comments for clarity purposes are more than welcomed.